# How to properly split on a non escaped delimiter?

Tags: java, regex, escaping, delimiter

I have the following example string:

```
A|B\|C\\|D\\\|E\\\\F
```

with | being the delimiter and \ being the escape character.
A proper split should look as follows:

```
A
B\|C\\
D\\\|E\\\\
F
```

Also I need this logic to be generally applicable in case the delimiter or the escape consists out of multiple characters.

I already have a regex which splits at the correct position, but it does not produce the desired output:

Regex:

```
(?<!\Q\\E)(?:(\Q\\\E)*)\Q|\E
```

Output:

```
A
B\|C
D\\\|E
F
```

I am usually testing here: https://regex101.com/, but am working in java so I have a little more capabilities.

Also tried the following with no positive result as well (doesn't work on the webpage, but in java just doesn't produce the desired result):

```
(?=(\Q\\\E){0,5})(?<!\Q\\E)\Q|\E
```

Comment: Do you mean your input is `A|B\|C\\|D\\\|E\\\\|F`?

Comment: yes (although not yet in string format) Java statement:
"A|B\\|C\\\\|D\\\\\\|E\\\\\\\\|F".split("proper_regex_here")

Comment: Do not use `split`, it won't be as stable as the extracting approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Extracting approach**

You can use a matching approach as it is the most stable and allows arbitrary amount of escaping `\` chars. You can use

```java
(?s)(?:\\.|[^\\|])+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pQBSBI/1). *Details*:

- `(?s)` - `Pattern.DOTALL` embedded flag option
- `(?:\\.|[^\\|])+` - one or more repetitions of `\` and then any one char, or any char but `\` and `|`.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/xD6kJt):

```java
String s = "A|B\\|C\\\\|D\\\\\\|E\\\\\\\\|F";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\|])+", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()){
    results.add(matcher.group());
} 
System.out.println(results); 
// => [A, B\|C\\, D\\\|E\\\\, F]
```

**Splitting approach (workaround for `split`)**

You may (ab)use the *constrained-width* lookbehind pattern support in Java regex and use limiting quantifier like `{0,1000}` instead of `*` quantifier. A work-around would look like

```java
String s = "A|B\\|C\\\\|D\\\\\\|E\\\\\\\\|F";
String[] results = s.split("(?<=(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\{2}){0,1000})\\|"); System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results));
```

See [this Java demo](https://ideone.com/uP0LsG).

Note `(?:\\{2}){0,1000}` part will only allow up to 1000 escaping backslashes that should suffice in most cases, I believe, but you might want to test this first. I'd still recommend the first solution.

*Details*:

- `(?<=` - start of a positive lookbehind:

  - `(?<!\\)` - a location not immediately preceded with a `\`
  - `(?:\\{2}){0,1000}` - zero to one thousand occurrences of double backslash
- `)` - end of the positive lookbehind
- `\|` - a `|` char.

Comment: While this answers the title of the question my question was maybe asked a bit incorrectly. I specifically need a regex which I can put inside the split function and which works with multiple characters for the delimiter and escape.

Comment: @FelixUnverzagt I'd recommend using *solutions* rather than *workarounds*.

Comment: Thanks a lot the second approach is working (sadly I need the logic this way as it is part of a bigger regex logic). I will try to adopt the first approach if I have time to think how to replace the other parts in the future